# Existence of solution to an equation

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{D^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ be a continuous function. I'm asked to prove that there exists a real number $r_0$ such that for all $r \geq r_0$, there exists x $\in$ $\mathbb{D^2}$ such that $f(x) = rx$.

The first trouble I have is that the image of f is not $D^2$, so it rules out (or not?) the possibility to apply Brower's fixed point theorem. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you missing a "there exists an $x$ such that"?

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the error, I just edited it.

Comment: Hint: you can use BFPT, but you need to massage your problem until it fits the conditions. How would you change the codomain of your function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb D^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous $f(\mathbb{D}^2)$ is compact and contained in a ball of radius $r>0$, $\mathbb{D}_r^2$. The contraction $c_r: \mathbb{D}^2_r \to \mathbb{D}^2$, $x\mapsto \frac{x}{r}$ composed with $f$ gives rise to a map $c_r\circ f: \mathbb{D}^2\to \mathbb{D}^2$.

If $r_0 := \max\{|x|:x\in f(\mathbb{D}^2)\}$ then for any $r\geq r_0$ the map $c_r\circ f: \mathbb{D}^2\to \mathbb{D}^2$ has a fixed point by Brouwer's theorem.